# Location of Amplifier for Signal Integrity

Tags: amplifier, sensor, signal-integrity

Let's say I have a photodiode that outputs a current with respect to incident light on the die. If this photodiode will be located 12 inches or so away from the control board, would it be better for signal integrity to filter and amplify this signal (transimpedance amp) close to the sensor (as in a small PCB with wire harness) or does it not matter? I do know that current is more immune to noise (i.e. 4-20mA systems). To me it might make sense to locate the amp closer, since the long lead could degrade the original signal?

Comment: Sure, better amplify a cleaner signal to increase SNR ratio of the outgoing signal. You can even consider digitizing it in some way (place a microcontoller with A/D) depending on your application.

Comment: What's the signal bandwidth? For high frequency designs, it's common to put the TIA within a few mm (even within the same TO can or ROSA [receiver optical sub-assembly]) of the photodiode.

Comment: @ThePhoton This isn't a high frequency design, it'll just be used to quantify some laser light driven by continuous wave (not pulsed).

Comment: Yes, locate the amp closer. Capacitive coupling into a 12 inch wire will drive currents into the wire that look the same as the currents from the photodiode. This means it would likely pickup lots of interference.